# Windows 8.1 Store app packaging compatibility issue

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have a Windows 8.1 app that I'm trying to upload on store. I've done it multiple times before, but now it's popping this error:

*Project "XXX" depends upon SDK "Microsoft Player Framework v1.8.1.0" which supports apps targeting "Windows 8.0". To verify whether "Microsoft Player Framework v1.8.1.0" is compatible with "Windows 8.1", contact the SDK author or see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309181.*

Only thing I remember doing is updating the "**Update 2**" for Visual Studio. Except that, everything is more or less the same. Previous versions of the app contained the **same Microsoft Player Framework version** and there were **no problems uploading to store**.

Also I'm coding in XAML/C#, but don't think it's relevant on the subject.

Comment: Player Framework was updated to v2.0 in May, it includes Windows 8.1 support.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. Although I don't understand, why don't you put it as an answer? Why use just a comment?

Comment: Also, now app is running perfectly and builds with no errors, but if I try to export it Create App Packages it shows old, non-existent errors. Any idea what's going on?